# Elasticsearch Memory Usage increases over time and is at 100%

Tags: elasticsearch, memory

I see that indexing performance degraded over a period of time in Elasticsearch. I see that the mem usage has slowly increased over a period of time until it became 100%. At this state I cannot index any more data. I have default shard settings - 5 primary and 1 replica. My index is time based with index created every hour to store coral service logs of various teams. An index size corresponds to about 3GB with 5 shards and with replica it is about 6GB. With a single shard and 0 replicas it comes to about 1.7 GB.
I am using ec2's i2.2x large hosts which offer 1.6TB space and 61GB RAM and 8 cores. 
I have set the heap size to 30GB.
Following is node statistics:
https://jpst.it/1eznd

Could you please help in fixing this? My whole cluster came down that I had to delete all the indices.

Comment: You will have to provide some more information.  Elastisearch version, how many total indices did u have before your nodes failed? What is your refresh interval? (default is 1 second). Can you see logs from the two failed nodes? The _nodes information you gave only has info about the currently active nodes (13). So that info is not very useful.

Comment: How fast do you index? How many documents per minute?

Comment: Around 30 indices. ES 6.1. 1s is refresh interval. When i made it to 30s i saw latency spikes every 30 second once. I have 5 data nodes. 3 master and 3 client nodes. About 1000 documents in one request , a request latency to ES was on avg 400 ms. The intention is to complete indexing within 20 mins. A single index would have about 30 lakh documents amounting to 3 GB. I have reduced the number of shards to 1 from 5 and using 1 replica. The indexing time has reduced after reducing no of shards but the overall latency has become 2000 ms from 400ms for a single request.

Comment: The last two sentences do not make sense to me. With a refresh interval of 1s, you saw indexing improve and latency go down when you Reduced shards? From what I know, the more shards you have the better indexing rate you get. The less shards you have the better latency you get. Is it necessary to have refresh interval at all? If you do not need to show up the index in your search results you can set refresh_interval = -1 which will disable refreshes, and the do a bulk index. Can you give paste your index settings, and your document mapping here? That might throw some light...